# Question about proof of Krein-Milman Theorem.

Tags: proof-verification, topological-vector-spaces

I am in the middle of working through the details of the proof of the Krein-Milman theorem in Rudin's Functional Analysis (Theorem 3.23), and I am stuck on one detail.  I will state the theorem and write down the relevant parts of the proof.

The Krein-Milman Theorem states:
Suppose $X$ is a topological vector space on which $X^*$ separates points.  If $K$ is a nonempty compact convex set in $X$, then $K$ is the closed convex hull of the set of its extreme points.

Proof (partial). Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the collection of all compact extreme sets of $K$.  Since $K\in \mathscr{P}$, $\mathscr{P}\not =\emptyset$.  We shall use the following property of $\mathscr{P}$:

(a) The intersection $S$ of any nonempty subcollection of $\mathscr{P}$ is a member of $\mathscr{P}$, unless $S=\emptyset$.

Choose some $S\in \mathscr{P}$.  Let $\mathscr{P}'$ be the collection of all members of $\mathscr{P}$ that are subsets of $S$.  Since $S\in \mathscr{P}'$, $\mathscr{P}'$ is not empty.  Partially order $\mathscr{P}'$ by set inclusion, let $\Omega$ be a maximal totally ordered subcollection of $\mathscr{P}'$, and let $M$ be the intersection of all members of $\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is a collection of compact sets with finite intersection property, $M\not =\emptyset$.  By (a), $M\in \mathscr{P}'$.

Here's my question: Why does the maximality of $\Omega$ imply that no proper subset of $M$ belongs to $\mathscr{P}$, as claimed in the next line of the proof?

$\text{ }$

Here is what I started on.  Suppose $A\subset M$. By means of contradiction, suppose $A\in \mathscr{P}$.  Since $M\subset S$, $A\subset S$ and $A\in \mathscr{P}'$.  Then $\Omega \subset \Omega \cup \{A\}$, which would contradict the maximality of $\Omega$ unless $A\in \Omega$.  But I cannot prove that $A\not \in \Omega$.  In fact, it must be that $A\in \Omega$ since $\Omega \subset \Omega \cup \{A\}$ and $\Omega$ is maximal.  Any ideas or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $A\in \Omega$, then $$M = \bigcap_{S\in\Omega} S = A \cap \bigcap_{S\in \Omega\setminus\{A\}} S \subset A.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A \subset \Omega$, then the intersection of all members of $\Omega$ would be contained in $A$, and so $M \subseteq A$.